# The meaning of implication

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

We have some predefined functions and those are

```
$M(x) = x$ is a woman

$D(x,y) = x$ is child of $y$

$P(x,y) = x$ is husband/wife of $y.$
```

And the task is to ofc in predicat. logic write these relation ships

```
$x$ is daughter of $y$

$x$ is grandfather of $y$

$x$ is aunt of $y$
```

The question is , what is right choice of logical operator in this$?$ Its an implication or conjunction. $=$

$x$ is daughter of $y$>>$D(x,y) \Rightarrow  M(x)$

$x$ is grandfather of $y$>> $D(z,x) \wedge D(y,z) \Rightarrow  M(y) \wedge  M(z)'$

$x$ is aunt of $y$ >> $D(x,z) \wedge D(u,z) \Rightarrow  D(y,u) \wedge M(x) $

does implication fits in those expression , if not , why$?$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Intuitively,

- conjunction represents "and"
- implication represents "if ... then ..."

For example, you should have $D(x,y) \wedge M(x)$ for the first question, as otherwise you are saying "**IF** $x$ is a child of $y$, **THEN** $x$ is a woman." What you really want to say is "$x$ is a child of $y$ **AND** $x$ is a woman."

You have mistakes in your other two answers as well; see if you can fix them.

Comment: oh , so implication is just like condition in programming ,which mean all implications should be replaced with conjuction? In those two answers

Comment: Yes, sort of, to the first comment, and a definite yes to the second.